# adding timer to microphone in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I m using a microphone class to record audio from user. I want to add an timer to show the user a live timer which keeps counting when the user speaks and stops once he is done. any idea how to add an timer when the microphone starts recording.
Also I want the limit the recording to particular time limit for example the user can speak only for 2 mins. Sample code would be really helpful

Comment: Save the starttime into a variable with DateTime.Now. Then use a Timer with a interval to update the recording time. You can subtract the current time from your variable and show that. Similar questions have been asked on stackoverflow. Search a bit more. I'm mobile so not able to do a lot of research for you :-) hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code counting 2 minutes and update `ElapsedTime` `TextBlock` with elapsed time

```
 DateTime beginTime = DateTime.Now;
 DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer()
 {
      Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
 };
 Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
 {
      double elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Substract(beginTime).TotalSeconds;
      ElapsedTime.Text = elapsedTime.ToString();
      if (elapsedTime > 120)
      {
           //Stop recording
           Timer.Stop();
      }
 }
 Timer.Start();
```

Hope this helps